# How to get JSON API response for call made from twilio?

Tags: python, django, twilio, twilio-api

I am unable to fetch the JSON response as shown in the [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-create-a-call-resource-and-specify-a-statuscallback-url&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x).

I have implemented a Programmable Voice program. I want to show the user the details of the call and if I get the JSON response I would be able to get all of them (cost, duration, status, etc).

```py
# views.py
def start_campaign(request, campaign_id):

    try:
        campaign = Campaign.objects.get(pk=campaign_id)
        account_sid = 'XXX'
        auth_token = 'XXX'
        client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

        phone_numbers = Contact.objects.filter(phone_book=campaign.phone_book)
        custom_url = 'http://XXX.ngrok.io/assets/' + str(campaign_id)

        for phone_number in phone_numbers:

            call = client.calls.create(
                method='GET',
                status_callback='http://XXX.ngrok.io/events',
                status_callback_event='completed',
                status_callback_method='GET',
                url=str(custom_url),
                to=str(phone_number),
                from_='+1XXX'
            )
            detail = client.calls(str(call.sid)).fetch()
            print(detail.price)

    except Campaign.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Campaign Does Not Exist")

    context = {
        'all_campaigns': campaign
    }

    return render(request, "CallCenter/start_campaign.html", context)


def events(request):
    status = request.GET.getlist('CallStatus', default=None)
    duration = request.GET.getlist('CallDuration', default=None)

    print("Duration:{}\nStatus:{}".format(duration, status))

    return render(request, "CallCenter/events.html")
```

In the terminal, I get a output which prints out the status and duration of the call from

"GET /events?Called=%2BXX&ToState=&CallerCountry=US&Direction=outbound-api&Timestamp=Sat,+12+Oct+2019+19:11:50+%2B0000&CallbackSource=call-progress-events&SipResponseCode=200&Ca
llerState=AL&ToZip=&SequenceNumber=0&CallSid=XXX&To=%2BXXX&CallerZip=35766&ToCountry=IN&CalledZip=&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&CalledCity=&CallStatus=completed&Duration=1&From=
%2BXXX&CallDuration=5&AccountSid=XXX&CalledCountry=IN&CallerCity=ESTILLFORK&ToCity=&FromCountry=US&Caller=%2B12563804721&FromCity=ESTILLFORK&CalledState=&FromZip=35766&Fro
mState=AL HTTP/1.1" 200 123

printing out

Duration:['5', '5']

Status:['completed', 'completed']

Unfortunately, I don't know how to ask for the JSON response from Twilio.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You're printing in a completely different view from the one where you make the Twilio call, and what you're printing is what is being sent from your frontend.

Comment: @DanielRoseman at ./start-campaign it creates a call resource which calls all the numbers present in the phonebook. Using the status_callback, I tried to create a JSON response as shown in the tutorial(example 3) on [Create a Call resource and specify a StatusCallbackEvent](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-create-a-call-resource-and-specify-a-statuscallback-url&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x), in it sends a GET request to ./events. I tried to follow the tutorial, but I feel that I'm lost.

Comment: But I don't understand why you think there should be a "JSON response". Twilio has called your callback endpoint with the parameters you see, and you've successfully printed two of them. What else are you expecting?

Comment: The Twilio python library is already parsing the JSON response into a python object that you can fetch properties from. The `call` object you have will include all the details. (Although, since you only just created the call, it won't have a duration or price yet. You'll want to store the SID and make the API call once the call is completed.)

Comment: @philnash How to make the API call? I know how to get the SID I'm trying to use if call.status == 'completed': pass. But it is not working and I am unable to find how to approach the problem

Comment: @DanielRoseman After Phil's comment, I realise that the JSON response shown at the tutorial is the call object. I am unable to find out how to make the API call after the call is completed.

Comment: *What* API call? You've made the call you need already. And Twilio in return has called your callback. What else do you want to do?

Comment: Later, after the call is finished, you can call on `client.calls(CALL_SID).fetch()` which will retrieve the latest information on the call. See the docs here for more: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource

Comment: @DanielRoseman I also need the price of the call. It is present in the call object(call.price), but if I ask for it as soon as the call object is created, it shows None since the call has not yet been made. That is why I was looking into how to make the API call after the call is completed. I thought the status_callback would solve it, but I feel I have not implemented it correctly and I was looking for some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the callback is received, you have the CallSid ID in the GET data. So you can use that to fetch the complete Call resource:

```
def events(request):
    sid = request.GET['CallSid']
    call = client.calls(sid).fetch()
    print(call.price)
```